# Calculate HMAC/MD5 truncated digest in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, md5, hmac, crypto++

I have a truncated digest from Crypto++. The digest was created with Hmac-md5 hashing algorithm. I need to calculate the same truncated digest in Node.js.

Is it enough to truncate the result in Node.js? Or does Crypto++ actually do more stuff?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you tried crypto-js? https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js

Comment: *"Or does CryptoPP method actually do more stuff..."* - Crypto++ only truncates the full digest to the smaller size. It does not do anything else.

Comment: Guessed so.

So the answer to my question would be:
create the hash,
assign it to a variable
slice the hash from 0 to number of bytes you want

and that's the equivalent in node-js, right?

Comment: @ProTheJoker - I don't know Node.js, so I can't answer the Node.js questions. It seems like it should be easy enough to answer with a Node.js test program. If you get different results, then you should look to the IETF test vectors because Crypto++ uses them.

Comment: with crypto-js, you have the cryptojs.MD5() function. that might help

Comment: Thank you guys, I solved it ^^

Also thanks to @jww for editing my post and correcting it.